# Unit testing issue with RegisterClassMap in CSVHelper after upgrading CsvHelper from 15.0.5 to 30.0.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, csvhelper

After upgrading CsvHelper, in the unit testing I am getting the
'Can not instantiate proxy of class: CsvHelper.CsvContext.
Could not find a parameterless constructor. (Parameter 'constructorArguments')' error.

In the Below line I am getting the error.

```
 _csvReader.Setup(s =>s.Context.RegisterClassMap<BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>()).Returns(It.IsAny<BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>());
```

This is the code where I need to write Unit Testing

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetListOfRecords<T, M>(string fileContent) where M : ClassMap
    {
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(fileContent))
        {
            using (var csvReader = _csvHelper.CreateReader(stringReader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
            {
                csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<M>();
                var records = csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
                return records;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the Unit Testing code

```cs
private ICsvHandler _csvHandler;
private Mock<IFactory> _csvHelper;
private Mock<IWriter> _csvWriter;
private Mock<IReader> _csvReader;
private Mock<IStreamWriter> _streamWriter;
private Fixture _fixture;

[SetUp]
public void CsvHanlderTestsSetup()
{
    _csvHelper = new Mock<IFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _csvWriter = new Mock<IWriter>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _csvReader = new Mock<IReader>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _streamWriter = new Mock<IStreamWriter>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _csvHandler = new CsvHandler(_csvHelper.Object, _streamWriter.Object);
    _fixture = new Fixture();

}

[Test]
public void Should_get_list_of_records()
{
    //arrange
    var fileContent = _fixture.Create<string>();
    IEnumerable<BulkAddUserTemplateModel> expected = new List<BulkAddUserTemplateModel>();

    _csvHelper.Setup(s => s.CreateReader(It.IsAny<StringReader>(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).Returns(_csvReader.Object);
    _csvReader.Setup(s =>s.Context.RegisterClassMap<BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>()).Returns(It.IsAny<BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>());
    _csvReader.Setup(s => s.GetRecords<BulkAddUserTemplateModel>()).Returns(expected);
    _csvReader.Setup(p => p.Dispose());

    //act
    var actual = _csvHandler.GetListOfRecords<BulkAddUserTemplateModel, BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>(fileContent);
    //assert
    actual.Should().Equals(expected);
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you might need to somehow mock your `CsvHelper` with a mocked `Parser`.  https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/CsvHelper.Tests.Mocks/ParserMock/-/php-parsermock-class-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

We need to mock csvcontext as well and pass reader or writer object as param in Setup
eg

```
        _csvContext = new Mock<CsvContext>(_csvReader.Object);
```

Then implement in method

```
            var fileContent = _fixture.Create<string>();
            IEnumerable<BulkAddUserTemplateModel> expected = _fixture.Create<IEnumerable<BulkAddUserTemplateModel>>();
            var configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = true //this seems like a default value, but explicit set is good for readability
            };

            _csvHelper.Setup(s => s.CreateReader(It.IsAny<StringReader>(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)).Returns(_csvReader.Object);
            _csvReader.Setup(s => s.Configuration).Returns(configuration);
            _csvReader.Setup(s => s.Context).Returns(_csvContext.Object);
            _csvReader.Setup(s => s.Context.RegisterClassMap<BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>()).Returns(It.IsAny<BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>());
            _csvReader.Setup(s => s.GetRecords<BulkAddUserTemplateModel>()).Returns(expected);
            _csvReader.Setup(p => p.Dispose());
//act
var actual = _csvHandler.GetListOfRecords<BulkAddUserTemplateModel, BulkAddUserTemplateModelMap>(fileContent);

//assert
actual.Should().Equals(expected);
```